# Error while installing jenkins in rhel in aws instance

Tags: redhat

sudo yum install jenkins -y

Error:
problem:cannot install the best candidate for the job
-nothing provides daemonize needed by jenkins-2.303.2-1.1.noarch
(try to add '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages or '--nobest' to use not only best candidate package)

Comment: did you try to install daemonize first?

Comment: yes ivthillo while doing  yum install epel -release  # for daemonize still showing a error :Unable to find a match: epel-release

Comment: what if you try sudo yum install epel-release and install daemonize after it. (Maybe you have to enable the epel repo too)

Answer (score 0):

The cause of this error is that the daemonize package is required, but it cannot be found in the repositories available on the system

`sudo dnf install daemonize`

It can be give you error. Before above pls run below command first

`sudo dnf install https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-8.noarch.rpm`